# Site returns 502.5 when connecting via port 80

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an small app which ditribute data via an REST api.
On the local host it works fine and from an other machine it works also fine if  i connect via an port except 80.

As soon as i bind port 80 and try to connect i get an 502.5 error.
Also there are no logs or events which give me further informations.

Comment: There's way too little information for us to be able to help you. Possibly interesting: [ASP.NET Core 2.1.1 fails with HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/945)

Comment: I suspect a virus checker or firewall is blocking port 80 (or used by another application).

Comment: When i change the path to the iis default page it works on port 80. The problem only occurs with an asp.net core application.